# Why does Module slow down StringMatchQ by 180 times?

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation, scoping, timing

I knew that `Module` is slower than `With` or `Block`, often by several times. But it surprises me that `Module` can slow down `StringMatchQ` by 180 times.

Starting with a fresh kernel, define the test functions (This test function comes from some complicated functions. I reduce the original one preserving the slow-down feature and find this least example.)

```
fModule[string_String] :=
    Module[ {str2},
        str2="x";
        StringMatchQ[string, 
            str1___/;str1==str2
        ]
    ];
fWith[string_String] :=
    With[ {str2="x"},
        StringMatchQ[string, 
            str1___/;str1==str2
        ]
    ];
fBlock[string_String] :=
    Block[ {str2},
        str2="x";
        StringMatchQ[string, 
            str1___/;str1==str2
        ]
    ];
fBare[string_String]:=
    StringMatchQ[string,
        str1___/;str1=="x"
    ];
```

then

```
fModule["x"]//RepeatedTiming
fWith["x"]//RepeatedTiming
fBlock["x"]//RepeatedTiming
fBare["x"]//RepeatedTiming

fModule["xa"]//AbsoluteTiming
fWith["xa"]//AbsoluteTiming
fBlock["xa"]//AbsoluteTiming
fBare["xa"]//AbsoluteTiming
```

gives
[image]

How to understand this? Does this occur only for `StringMatchQ`, or for string manipulations, or even for some larger class of functions?

---

For convenience,

```
compare[f_,timing_] :=
    (
        fModule//Clear;
        fBare//Clear;
        fModule[string_String] :=
            Module[ {str2},
                str2 = "x";
                f[string, 
                    str1___/;str1==str2
                ]
            ];
        fBare[string_String] :=
            f[string,
                str1___/;str1=="x"
            ];
        fModule["x"]//timing//Sow;
        fBare["x"]//timing//Sow;
    )//Reap//Part[#,2,1]&//Replace[{list1_,list2_}:>{list1,list2,list1[[1]]/list2[[1]]}]
```

[image]

The `AbsoluteTiming` without `Module` is not accurate, but still shows the features.

---

As suggested by @rnotlnglgq, we modify the condition with a decorator, then this magic slow-down disappears!

```
compare[f_,timing_,decorator_] :=
    (
        fModule//Clear;
        fBare//Clear;
        fModule[string_String] :=
            Module[ {str2 = "x"},
                f[string, 
                    str1___/;decorator[str1==str2]
                ]
            ];
        fBare[string_String] :=
            f[string,
                str1___/;str1=="x"
            ];
        fModule["x"]//timing//Sow;
        fBare["x"]//timing//Sow;
    )//Reap//Part[#,2,1]&//Replace[{list1_,list2_}:>{list1,list2,list1[[1]]/list2[[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the reason is that Module allocates memory each time it is called.

Comment: @DanielHuber  The `AbsoluteTiming` is also much slower. I hopefully expect this slow-down is rare and only for some special functions, since `Module` has not been deprecated during this thirty years.

Comment: I think @DanielHuber is correct `fBlock3[string_String] := Block[ {str2}, StringMatchQ[string, str1___/;str1=="x" ] ]; ` is not significantly slower. The slow down is on `str2="x"`.

Comment: Hi guys, I test more examples with AbsoluteTiming and RepeatedTiming.

Comment: A minimal example for this magic: `Do[Module[{sym}, StringMatchQ[_/;(sym;True)]@"x"],1*^4] //AbsoluteTiming`. It will be much faster if you add a `Evaluate` in the `Condition`.

Comment: @DanielHuber yet if you do timings with `Hold@StringMatchQ[...` then differences are much smaller, 2-3x. Puzzling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this the discrepancy is caused by some type of caching of the string pattern. And since `Module` is the only version that causes the string pattern to change each time (since the variable name is localized to a different one each time), it's the only one not benefitting from this caching.

Some tests showing that this is likely what's happening:

- On a fresh kernel:

  ```
  Table[AbsoluteTiming@StringMatchQ["x", str1___ /; str1 == "x"], 10]
  (* {{0.0006325, True}, {5.8*10^-6, True}, {2.4*10^-6, 
    True}, {2.4*10^-6, True}, {2.6*10^-6, True}, {2.2*10^-6, 
    True}, {2.4*10^-6, True}, {2.3*10^-6, True}, {2.5*10^-6, 
    True}, {2.5*10^-6, True}} *)
  ```

  As you can see, the first run is ~100x slower than the following ones. (there is still some warm-up on subsequent runs of the line above, but not nearly as severe)
- Adding a `fDelayedModule` variant that "removes" `Module` from the timing, and only keeps the localized variables:

  ```
  fModule[string_String] := Module[{str2}, str2 = "x";
     StringMatchQ[string, str1___ /; str1 == str2]];
  fWith[string_String] := 
    With[{str2 = "x"}, StringMatchQ[string, str1___ /; str1 == str2]];
  fBlock[string_String] := Block[{str2}, str2 = "x";
     StringMatchQ[string, str1___ /; str1 == str2]];
  fBare[string_String] := StringMatchQ[string, str1___ /; str1 == "x"];
  fDelayedModule[string_String] := Module[{str2}, str2 = "x";
     Hold[StringMatchQ[string, str1___ /; str1 == str2]]];

  Table[fModule["x"], 1000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
  With[{t = Table[fDelayedModule["x"], 1000]},
    t // ReleaseHold // AbsoluteTiming // First]
  Table[fWith["x"], 1000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
  Table[fBlock["x"], 1000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
  Table[fBare["x"], 1000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
  (* 0.35875 *)
  (* 0.322435 *)
  (* 0.0037334 *)
  (* 0.0030231 *)
  (* 0.0043415 *)
  ```

  As you can see, most of the slowdown is present even if we run the `Module` outside of the timed part, and simply return the expression to be run as `Hold[StringMatchQ[...]]`
- Running the test against 1000 unique characters in place of `"x"`:

  ```
  (
       fModule[string_String] := Module[{str2}, str2 = #;
         StringMatchQ[string, str1___ /; str1 == str2]];
       fModule[#]
       ) & /@ FromCharacterCode /@ Range@1000 // AbsoluteTiming // First
  (* 0.391135 *)

  (
       fBare[string_String] :=
        StringMatchQ[string, str1___ /; str1 == #];
       fBare[#]
       ) & /@ FromCharacterCode /@ Range@1000 // AbsoluteTiming // First
  (* 0.344281 *)
  ```

  As you can see, the bare version has almost no speed advantage over `Module` when encountering the pattern for the first time.
- Adding [`ClearSystemCache[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearSystemCache.html) before the calls:

  ```
  Table[ClearSystemCache[]; fModule["x"], 1000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
  Table[ClearSystemCache[]; fBare["x"], 1000] // AbsoluteTiming // First
  (* 0.498588 *)
  (* 0.506117 *)
  ```

  Again, both versions are now equally fast.

Comment: Convicing. The `ClearSystemCache[]` test is determinate.

Comment: It seems not configurable, as I don't see something like `"StringPatternCache"` in `SystemOptions[]`. And it depends neither on `"Numeric"` nor `"Symbolic"` cache option.

Comment: There is this ``StringPattern`SetStringPatternCache`` though I don't know what is it.

Answer (score 6):

I did some tests to see the difference between Module and Block because I usually use Module and it would scare me if it is really so slow in general.

Lets start with a very simple code that more or less only check the setup:

```
f1 := Module[{a}, a = 2];
f2 := Block[{a}, a = 2];

Do[f1, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming
Do[f2, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming

{1.19221, Null}
{0.304252, Null}
```

No much difference here. Now with a bit more calculations:

```
f1 := Module[{a, b}, a = Sqrt[2.]; b = a; b^2];
f2 := Block[{a, b}, a = Sqrt[2.]; b = a; b^2];

Do[f1, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming
Do[f2, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming

{3.13645, Null}}
{1.09971, Null}
```

This shows also no difference. Next let us check with StringMatchQ to see if this is the culprit:

```
f1 := Module[{a = "one", b = "one"}, StringMatchQ[a, b]];
f2 := Block[{a = "one", b = "one"}, StringMatchQ[a, b]];

Do[f1, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming
Do[f2, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming

{2.04834, Null}
{0.641031, Null}
```

Next we can add a condition:

```
f1 := Module[{a = "one", b = "one"}, 
   StringMatchQ[a, b] /; a == "one"];
f2 := Block[{a = "one", b = "one"}, StringMatchQ[a, b] /; a == "one"];

Do[f1, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming
Do[f2, 10^6] // RepeatedTiming

{3.05893, Null}
{1.03161, Null}
```

Therefore it looks like Module is in general about 3 time slower than Block.

Comment: I have already been scared XD, since most of my functions use `Module` to avoid the extra features of With and Block. I hope this only occurs for string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 6):

A smaller example for reduplicating it:

```
Do[Module[{sym},
    StringMatchQ[___/;(sym;True)]@""
],1*^4] //AbsoluteTiming //First
```

I got `2.15651` on my machine, while the following edition with an extra `Evaluate`

```
Do[Module[{sym},
    StringMatchQ[___/;Evaluate[sym;True]]@""
],1*^4] //AbsoluteTiming //First
```

gives `0.030968` (70x faster).

And this seems a unique behavior for string pattern matching, expression matching(including sequence matching) doesn't have this problem. And no matter if the basic pattern is `Blank` or `BlankSequence`.

Not only `Evaluate`, the slowing behavior can be eliminated by this:

```
Union@Table[Module[{sym="x"},
    StringMatchQ[_/;(ToExpression["sym$"<>ToString@--$ModuleNumber]=="x")]@"x"
],1*^4] //AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.077667, {True}} *)
```

The `ToExpression` breaks the lexicon scoping, but has reserved many other missions(create symbols, assignment, symbol reference, etc.)

Still confusing.

Comment: Thanks for this magic to bypass this problem!